# Multiple sites on one Ubuntu server with two network card

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu

I've got following configuration in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.32.27   site1.com site1.com
192.168.32.28   site2.com site2.com
```

Following configuration for site1:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName site1.com
   ServerAlias www.site1.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
   Redirect permanent / https://site1.com
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerAdmin admin@site1.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/site1
 </VirtualHost>
```

Following configuration for site2:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName site2.com
   ServerAlias www.site2.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
   Redirect permanent / https://site2.com
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerAdmin admin@site2.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/site2
 </VirtualHost>
```

However, when put in my address 192.168.32.28 which is address of my second network card I'm still redirected to 192.168.32.27.

Could you help me to understand possible reasons why it's not working as supposed?